# Two array types into one function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a form where you click a button and a collection of elements need the opacity changed and the radio or checkbox selected.  I have a bunch of these in the form so I need assistance with creating this type of array. Some of the IDs are dp001, dp002 …. dp050 so there needs to be a condition appending the prefix to it when it gets to dp010. This collection of elements I want to change the opacity. The other collection of elements isn't in any particular order but I want to collect them and make them checked. Somewhere I created a FUBAR :)

Fiddle won't work … really pi$$ing me off don't know why jsfiddle refuses to load javascript for me.  [Is This Fiddle FUBAR?](http://jsfiddle.net/DivineChef/N7h9a/2/)

On my web server the alert works fine the doesn't do what I want.
[Javscript works on my server check it out.](http://triplewww.com/cm/bs/base_arrays.html)

HTML

```
<div id="dp001">Item #1 <input type="radio" id="abc005"></div>
<div id="dp002">Item #2 <input type="radio" id="abc008"></div>
<div id="dp003">Item #3 <input type="checkbox" id="abc010"></div>
<div id="dp004">Item #4 <input type="checkbox" id="abc020"></div>
<div id="dp005">Item #5</div>
<div id="dp006">Item #6</div>
<div id="dp007">Item #7</div>
<div id="dp008">Item #8</div>
<div id="dp009">Item #9</div>
<div id="dp010">Item #10</div>
<div id="dp011">Item #11</div>
<button type="button" onclick="DoStuff();">Click</button>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
  function DoStuff() {
   var items = null;
   var checkMe = ["abc005" , "abc0008" , "abc010" , "abc020"];
   for (i=1 ; i < 12 ; i++) {
   if (i < 10) {
   items = 'dp00' + i;
   } else {
   items = 'dp0' + i;
   }
  }
   alert("ding");
   document.getElementById("items").style.opacity="0.5";
   document.getElementById("checkMe").checked = true;

 }
```

Comment: (In jsFiddle, if you're using inline JS function calls, you have to make them global. Your fiddle defines `DoStuff` in an onload wrapper = not global, so the inline event handler doesn't know `DoStuff`. Fix = use `No wrap - in body`.)

Comment: Thanks Rudie no wrap - in body is the fix it was driving me nuts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need

```
function DoStuff() {
    var checkMe = ["abc005" , "abc0008" , "abc010" , "abc020"];
    for (var i=1; i < 12; i++) {
        var items = 'dp0' + (i<10 ? '0' : '') + i;
        document.getElementById(items).style.opacity = 0.5;
    }
    for (var i=0, l=checkMe.length; i<l; ++i)
        document.getElementById(checkMe[i]).checked = true;
}
```

Problems with your code:

- `"items"` is a literal string, not the variable `items`. Same for `"checkMe"`.
- You must change each element inside the loop, not outside.
- You don't declare variable `i`
- You can use the ternary conditional to simplify code (optional)

Comment: Great it works except I want all the checkboxes and radio buttons checked it only checks the first one for me.

Comment: @user3362232 In html you have `id="abc008"` but in the array `"abc0008"`. Then `getElementById` returns null, and trying to set `checked` property throws an error that stops the loop.

Comment: Yes you are correct thanks for the help and correction/explanations.